# How to use IComparable to sort a dictionary of Class Objects

Tags: c#, console

So I am trying to implement a sort on a dictionary to sort alphabetically by name. My class inherits IComparable and contains a compareTo(Object alpha)
method in the class. My problem is trying to implement this onto my dictionary and sort in that way.

I am reading from all names from a file and placing into a dictionary

I basically just want to know how to use this method since I could just extract name from the dictionary and sort then plug back in and get the other data I need. If anyone can help that would be great.

Here is the CompareTo method:

```
    public int CompareTo(Object alpha)
    {
        if (alpha == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Subreddit rightOp = alpha as Subreddit;  


        if (rightOp != null) 
            return name.CompareTo(rightOp.name);  
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("[Subreddit]:CompareTo argument is 
        not a Subreddit");
     }
```

Comment: Quick notes: 1) if the argument is `null`, *don't throw*. By the definition of `IComparable`, `this` is greater than `null` so return 1. See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable). 2) While you're at it, implement `IComparable<Subreddit>` and then call that implementation in `IComparable.CompareTo` when `rightOp != null`.

Comment: @madreflection That makes sense. So when it can make the comparison I can call compare and when i call the method I plug in the collection with data to compare each element?

Comment: By "dictionary" you mean [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2)? This class does not support sorting. The keys are only comparable for equality. They are either equal or not equal.

Comment: *You* shouldn't be calling the method. The sorting algorithm calls it. You just provide the method(s) so that the algorithm doesn't have to know how to determine when a `Subreddit` is greater than, less than, or equal to another `Subreddit`. Having thought about it more, `Subreddit` instances don't really have a natural order (ordering by name is arbitrary, not natural). You really should be implementing a separate object that implements `IComparer<T>` that orders `Subreddit` instances by name.

Comment: But if the data is in a collection how would it compare objects since the data is already stored? I think that is what is mostly confusing me right now

Comment: @Johnkant Have you considered using `SortedDictionary`?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` with `IComparer<T>` you should use `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8 for details and examples

The `new SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>()` will use `Comparer<T>.Default` and if type `TKey` implements the `System.IComparable<T>` generic interface, the default comparer uses that implementation. or you pass a comparer to the constructor. Here is an example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<Subreddit, Payload>(new KeyComparer());
            sortedDictionary.Add(new Subreddit {Name = "B"}, new Payload());
            sortedDictionary.Add(new Subreddit {Name = "A"}, new Payload());
            sortedDictionary.Add(new Subreddit {Name = "C"}, new Payload());

            foreach (var keyValuePair in sortedDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{keyValuePair.Key.Name}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit program.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Subreddit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Payload
    {
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public int Data2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class KeyComparer : IComparer<Subreddit>
    {
        public int Compare(Subreddit x, Subreddit y)
        {
            if (x?.Name == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("[Subreddit]:CompareTo argument is not a Subreddit", nameof(x));
            if (y?.Name == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("[Subreddit]:CompareTo argument is not a Subreddit", nameof(y));

            return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }
    }
}

/*
  The Output will be:
  A
  B
  C
*/
```

If the key is a string only you do not need the class `Subreddit` with only one string property. You could simplify it to this and use the default implementation to sort strings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, Payload>();
            sortedDictionary.Add("B", new Payload());
            sortedDictionary.Add("A", new Payload());
            sortedDictionary.Add("C", new Payload());

            foreach (var keyValuePair in sortedDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{keyValuePair.Key}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit program.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Payload
    {
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public int Data2 { get; set; }
    }
}

/*
  The Output will be:
  A
  B
  C
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike List and Array Dictionary doesn't support sorting where you could implement IComparable interface and add your sort logic into CompareTo method.

But you can create your custom Comparer to use in OrderBy to somehow get the Dictionary items ordered as per your own requirement and return to a list of KeyValuePair. This is how you do this.

implement IComparer interface with given type, KeyValuePair TKey,TValue in your case, implement the Compare method with your comparison logic:

```
public class MyDictionaryComparer : IComparer<KeyValuePair<Subreddit, int>>
{
  public int Compare(KeyValuePair<Subreddit, int> lhs, KeyValuePair<Subreddit, int> rhs)
  {
    return lhs.Key.name.CompareTo(rhs.Key.name);
  }
}
```

Use:

```
Dictionary<Subreddit, int> data = new Dictionary<Subreddit, int>();
//Add some data

var sortedData = data.OrderBy(item => item, new MyDictionaryComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I ended up doing was creating an ArrayList of just Dicitonary.value.names

Then I call ArrayList.sort() which uses the IComparable interface and 
my CompareTo(Object Alpha) to sort by name descending.

Once I had the sorted names in the array I used 2 foreach loops to compare the name values in the sorted ArrayList and the original dictionary with the other values I needed. Since I was checking the sorted ArrayList against the dictionary it automatically grabbed the data  with the names in sorted Order.

From here I took all values associated with that name and threw it into another dictionary that was completely sorted. Now its probably not running at O(n) time but it works... Here's the code:

```
 public void sortDictionaryByName()
    {
        //GOAL: Get all the values from the dictionary into a list that can use the 
          .sort method

        ArrayList sortedNames = new ArrayList();


        foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Subreddit> value in subredditsDictionary)
        {
            sortedNames.Add(value.Value.name.ToString());
        }

        sortedNames.Sort();

        foreach (var value in sortedNames)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Subreddit> key in subredditsDictionary)
            {
                if (value.ToString() == key.Value.name.ToString())
                {
                    Subreddit tempData = new Subreddit
                    {
                        subID = key.Key,
                        name = key.Value.name,
                        members = key.Value.members,
                        active = key.Value.active
                    };

                    sortedDictionary.Add(tempData.subID, tempData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```